# How to select files between certain hours?

Tags: powershell

I have a folder contains a lot of files, I want to copy files only between 2PM and 3PM on a Thursday and Friday every week.

How can I do this "between hours" in PowerShell?

**Update:** OK, I sorted out, not sure if this is the best way. but it works

```
$source = path
$dest = path
$files = Get-ChildItem $source
foreach ($a in $files) {
    if ($a.CreationTime -gt (Get-Date).Date -and $a.CreationTime.Hour -ge 14 -and $a.CreationTime.Hour -lt 15) {
        Copy-Item -Path $a.FullName -Destination $dest
    }
}
```

Comment: create a datetime object for each of the max/min times, and then compare the object timestamp with those. something like `$Min -lt $_.TimeStamp -and $_.TimeStamp -lt $Max` seems likely to work. [*grin*]

Comment: A file has two date/times associated with it - creation and last modified. Which are you interested in (or are you merely interested in executing the script during those periods)?

Comment: creation date and time is the one to use. thx

Comment: Suppose I were to run your script this coming Saturday. Do you only want those files created today or tomorrow, or files created on _any_ Thursday or Friday, between 2PM and 3PM?

Comment: Also, do you want the date/time based on local time for the computer on which the script is running, or do you want UTC?

Comment: I sorted out. updated posted. thank you all